# Add element to laravel route http://mywebsite/[element]/myroute - Laravel and VueJS

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I am using Laravel and vueJS.

Here are my routes in web.php

```
Route::get('languages/list', 'UtilsController@getListLanguages');
Route::get('runners/{n}', 'RunnerController@runner')->name('runners.runner');
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
```

Some are routing directly to views, some do it through a controller

```
public function runner($id){
        $array=$this->runnerinfo($id);
        return view('runners/runner', ['runner' => json_encode($array)] );
}
```

I would like to add the language in each of these routes, but I am not using Laravel's language, as I use VueJS

Here is the language switch in the navbar

```
<div class="locale-changer" aria-labelledby="dropdown07">
                        <select class="dropdown-menu-lang " aria-labelledby="dropdown07" v-model="$i18n.locale"  >
                            <option class="dropdown-item-lang" v-for="(lang, i) in langs" :key="`Lang${i}`" :value="lang">{{ lang }}</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
```

I use vue-i18n (app.js)

```
    import VueInternationalization from 'vue-i18n';
    import Locale from './vue-i18n-locales.generated.js';
    const lang = document.documentElement.lang.substr(0, 2); 

    const i18n = new VueInternationalization({
        locale: lang,
        messages: Locale
    });
    const app = new Vue({
        i18n
    }).$mount('#app');
```

And I use it like this

```
 <a class="nav-link navbar-whitepanel selected" href="#about">{{$t('runner.about')}} <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
```

Is there any way to add the language in the laravel routes? (or any element I could use in any page).

Thanks a lot in advance, I have no idea how to do this

Comment: Consider using URL parameter like `domain.com/url?lang=en` or router parameter `domain.com/en/url`

Comment: yes thanks, that s actually better. but how to do this?

Comment: You ask about how to add url parameter with js?

Comment: Actually after a lot of thinking I would like the route like this: http://mywebsite.com/en/myroute.
Is there any way to add it in all routes using laravel?

Comment: You can create a route group for that prefix and wrap all current routes in it